# I am try to write the DDL script for a DB. I am trying to link the the fields area_number and seat_number with the table tickets

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I keep getting the

> Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint.

The table `tickets` will build, if I remove `area_number` and `seat_number` as  FOREIGN KEYS.

-- **Area**:

```
CREATE TABLE area ( 
    venue_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    area_number INTEGER(5) NOT NULL, 
    seat_number INTEGER(5) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (venue_name),
    PRIMARY KEY (area_number),
    PRIMARY KEY (seat_number),
    FOREIGN KEY(venue_name) REFERENCES venue(venue_name) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

-- **Tickets**:

```
CREATE TABLE tickets( 
    ticket_code VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL, 
    venue_name VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL, 
    ticket_type VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    event_name VARCHAR (60) NOT NULL,
    area_number INTEGER (5),
    seat_number INTEGER (5), 
    PRIMARY KEY(ticket_code), 
    FOREIGN KEY (ticket_type) REFERENCES ticket_type (ticket_type), 
    FOREIGN KEY (venue_name) REFERENCES venue (venue_name) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (event_name) REFERENCES _event (event_name) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (area_number) REFERENCES area (area_number),
    FOREIGN KEY (seat_number) REFERENCES area (seat_number));
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure area_number and seat_number are primary keys in area. A foreign key must reference a primary key in the target table.

Comment: I've changed the table area to: -- Area:
CREATE TABLE area ( 
venue_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
area_number INTEGER(5) NOT NULL, 
seat_number INTEGER(5) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (venue_name, area_number, seat_number),
FOREIGN KEY(venue_name) REFERENCES venue(venue_name) ON DELETE CASCADE ); still no luck

Comment: You tagged this question as mySQL and SQL Server. I used SSMS and SQL Server:

There are some design issues here. In the area table you have all three fields as primary keys. You can't do that. When I run your script I get:

Msg 8110, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Cannot add multiple PRIMARY KEY constraints to table 'area'.
Msg 8110, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Cannot add multiple PRIMARY KEY constraints to table 'area'.
Msg 2716, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column, parameter, or variable #2: Cannot specify a column width on data type int.